# Query to find districts with at least one value in assets table

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my SQL query:

```
select count(*) from district
```

but i want to select only all districts that have at least 1 value in table assets stored. (can be more than 1)

so

```
select all districts that have at least 1 entry in assets
```

table assets:
id name district_id

table district
id name

How can I do that?

Comment: Just a note that while it's useful to know that you're using Postgres in case there are advanced tricks you can use, this particular problem is pretty basic SQL, and would have the same solution on any DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*)
from district
where exists (
    select 1
    from assets
    where district_id = district.id
)
```